# Why I can't change the foreground of the label while declare a style of textblock?

Tags: wpf

I wanna to set the default foreground of textblock as #FF575757, so I code this in the APP.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF575757"></Setter>
            </Style>
```

It runs well.

Whereas, after I code a button with a control template, I found I can not change the foreground no matter set foreground value in XAML or hover it :

```
  <Button Foreground="Green">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Name="B" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True" ToolTip="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}">
                                    <Label FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Name="TB" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></Label>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="false" />
                                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="TB" Value="White"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

I took a long time to found the problem and finally I found one thing casually:
If I delete the textblock style in APP.xaml, the foreground problem can solve.
But I feel strange that I just only declare the default style of textblock but not the label. Why the style of textblock affects the label control?

What's more, if the style causes this. How can I not only set the default foreground but also make it can change anytime as we want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wpf label is a content control.

When you set or bind the content of a label to a string a textblock is created and it's the text of that you are setting.

Comment: But is there any other way let me set the default foreground as #FF575757 and I can change it any time as I want?

Comment: You would need the trigger to be on textblock. You're setting foreground on the button. That won't over-ride whatever is set on a textblock within the button.

Comment: However, I have TemplateBinded the foreground to the Label control yet. The foreground of Label control will change while I change the foreground of Button, right?

Comment: And also, it seems do not override it but something like restrict foreground to the value in style. I have created a brand new project with the code above to test it, and it turn out to be true. I don't know why it will be this.

Comment: Like i said above. There's a textblock in the label. Your style sets the foreground of textblock which will mean it uses that value rather than any it would inherit.

Comment: You mean the textblock inside the label will inherit the style but not use what I set in XAML, right? Now my problem is how can I set all the textblock default foreground to #575757 and I can change it in the foreground of the button also.

Comment: Start by using a textblock. Then give it a style or set it's style to {x:Null}